# UITableViewController doesn't refresh correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, object, nsmutablearray

I'm building an app (UITabBar) where I'm storing a NSMutableArray of custom objects. My custom object is called **DayModel**.

My DayModel.h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface DayModel : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *mydate;
@property (nonatomic) float myFloat;

@end
```

My DayModel.m file:

```
#import "DayModel.h"

@implementation DayModel

@synthesize myDate, myFloat;

-(id)init {
// Init self
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    // Setup
}
return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder;
{
[coder encodeObject:self.myDate forKey:@"myDate"];
[coder encodeObject:self.myFloat forKey:@"myFloat"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder;
{
self = [[DayModel alloc] init];
if (self != nil)
{
    self.myDate = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"myDate"];
    self.myFloat = [coder decodeFloatForKey:@"myFloat"];
}
return self;
}

@end
```

The "main" ViewController, saving the new objects:

```
// Add data to the DayModel class
DayModel *currentDay = [[DayModel alloc] init];
currentDay.myDate = myDate;
currentDay.myFloat = myFloat;

// Add currentDay to the _objects NSMutableArray
[_objects insertObject:currentDay atIndex:0];

// Save this array using NSKeyedArchiver
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:_objects] forKey:@"objects"];
```

my UITableViewController displaying this:

**viewWillAppear**

```
    // Load the _objects array
NSData *objectsData = [defaults objectForKey:@"objects"];
if (objectsData != nil)
{
    NSArray *oldArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:objectsData];
    if (oldArray != nil)
    {
        _objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:oldArray];
    } else
    {
        _objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
} else
{
    _objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

Other methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [_objects count];
}
```

Loading the data:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Get the DayModel
DayModel *currentModel = [[DayModel alloc] init];
currentModel = _objects[indexPath.row];

// Get the UILabels
UILabel *dateLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:10];
UILabel *floatLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:20];

// Create the DateFormatter
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];

// Set the text
dateLabel.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentModel.myDate];
floatLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f", currentModel.myFloat];

return cell;
}
```

Reproducing the problem:

- Add item from tab nr 1
- Go to tab nr 2 (table). Data is displayed correctly
- Go to tab nr 1 and add new object
- Go to tab nr 2 (table). New item is displayed with data from previews item, not new data.

When the app is reloaded, the table displays correctly.

**EDIT**

What happens is that the new item is added at index 0 to appear at the top of the list, while the tableview class get's the new information from the last row when it should be getting it from the top. How can I "reverse" this?

Thanks!
Erik

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by reloading the whole list, not only adding the new item. This code is going under the lines loading the list from NSUserDefaults (viewWillAppear).

```
// Reload the UITableView completely
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Please tell me if there's a better solution:)